# Laravel and vue csrf-token in <head>?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I am adding csrf to meta:

```
<head>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
```

but in bootstrap.js

```
let token1 = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
let token2 = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');
```

`token1` returns  `meta` array, but `token2` returns `null`? Why?

Comment: Can not reproduce. Assume that the second one is looking for the element before it exists. When both of those are run after it exists they both return the element, even when script is run in `<head>`

Comment: If the JS is running in the head without being inside of a “ready” event handler, then the `head` node will be null since the `head` isn’t finished yet. It should be the null if you use `document.querySelector('head meta[name="csrf-token"]')` for the same reason I just said — the head doesn’t exist yet.

Comment: @Nate was thinking same thing but when tested in both chrome and firefox it did work http://plnkr.co/edit/14peDqiHFKgXZZ1kvtHl?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, just figured out why I get this null. `php artisan optimize:clear` and no issues on csrf. I was using inline templates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that also worked without the '.head.' in the script.

In my case, I had a debugging script "echo" causing raw text above the

Broken Header

```
TEXTBEFORE<!DOCTYPE html><head>
```

GOOD

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head>
```